# How to retrieve data int http by using Asyntask - android

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement an app that requires user logging. I am able to store the username and password to the http client to handle the authentication. However, I have a trouble to retrieve the username. Here is my code, and I cant find where the bug is:

```
public class UserAccountInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
     @Override
     protected List<String> doInBackground(String... url) {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(BaseActivity.PRODUCT_URI);
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                //listofproduct = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.d(TAG, data);
                    JSONObject myjson;

                    try {
                        myjson = new JSONObject(data);
                        JSONArray array = myjson.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            list.add(obj.get("name").toString());
                            //listofproduct.add(obj.get("name").toString());
                        }
                        //Log.d("SHOWPRODUCT", "" + list.size());
                        /*for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
                            Log.d("SHOWPRODUCT", "" + list.get(i));
                        }*/

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error in parsing JSON");
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "ClientProtocolException while trying to connect to GAE");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "IOException while trying to connect to GAE");
                }
         return list;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
            super.onPostExecute(list);
     }

 }
```

And this is the code I handle login verification:

```
if( view == bt_login ){
        UserAccountInfo task = new UserAccountInfo();
        task.execute( UserLogin.USER_URI );
        //Log.i("USerLogin", "" + list.size());
        for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
            if( accountName.equals(list.get(i))) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( UserLogin.this, ShowProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity( myIntent );
            }
            Log.i("USERLOGIN", "" + list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onPostExecute` method to handle login verification after `doInBackground` method execution change your code as:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
       super.onPostExecute(list);
          // do login verification here....
        for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
          if( accountName.equals(list.get(i))) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent( UserLogin.this, 
                                  ShowProductsActivity.class);
             startActivity( myIntent );
           }
         Log.i("USERLOGIN", "" + list.get(i));
        }
 }
```